# read image from socket using python kivy

Tags: python, image, sockets, opencv, kivy

I'm trying to build a GUI for a python application with the kivy library. The GUI should work as a client to the main application. And they shouold communicate through sockets. I've no idea how to open the Image on the client side. In the main application the Image exists as opencv image object and I think I should send it as text.

But how can I get this image String to become a kivy image object? I'm new to kivy and in the documentation all I found is reading an image from file or from web: [https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html#)

Pls let me know if I'm on a wrong way and shouldn't use sockets for this. Some details: Server and Client are running on RaspberryPi3 and the server's output is a 500x500px image each second.

Comment: see [kivy.core.image](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.image.html) - but it expects data compressed as "png", 'jpg", etc. and openCV can give you raw data.

Comment: Base64 string is string others is a file object ! You can't collect image data if got any header error ! use `#! /usr/bin/python -u`(binary mode/other modes encode image data(corrupted image)), `image = file(u"test.jpg","rb").read()`, `print 'Content-Type:image/jpg\nContent-Length:%d\n'%len(image)`, `print image` returned an image but filename is last part of request_path

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found another way than using kivy.image or kivy.core.image the module kivy.graphics.texture. The server script uses `data = numpy_arrray.tostring()` than i send the string to the socket and on the client I can use
`texture.blit_buffer(data, bufferfmt="ubyte", colorfmt="rgb")`

Comment: here is the link: [kivy.graphics.texture](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.texture.html?highlight=texture#module-kivy.graphics.texture) And before we can use the texture we need to created forgot that line: `texture = Texture.create(size=(1280, 1024), colorfmt='rgb')`